# Issue setting Silverlight MediaElement Position to NaturalDuration

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

When I set the Position to NaturalDuration on a MediaElement, the position is actually not set.  I am using WMV files.

```
_media.Position = _media.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
```

the MediaElement does not actually go to the end of the clip. I do check for the opened and not playing states.  The video is completely buffered.

It always goes to a few frames before the end of the clip. It even backs up a few frames if the video was already at the end.  When I try to reset it again, it still fails.  The only way to get to the end of the clip is to play the material.

Is this a known Silverlight Issue?  Will it be fixed in the Silverlight5 release?  Is there a known workaround?